# PHP array not saving values as I expected

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, save

Today I was recoding an old program in PHP and I used arrays to organize it better.
After coding it, when I tested it I realized that the arrays were not saving the values as I expected them to do.
(I'm kind of a newbie in PHP)

Here is how I defined the arrays:

```
/* Mysql settings */
$mysql = array();

$mysql['track'] = array();
$mysql['track']['visitors'] = array();
$mysql['track']['visitors']['query'] = "SELECT `uid`, `referer` FROM `track` WHERE (`time` >= '".$time['request']['start']."' AND `time` < '".$time['request']['end']."') GROUP BY `uid`";
```

I used var_dum to see how the values where saved and made an mysql request:

```
var_dump($mysql['track']);
...
mysql_query($mysql['track']['visitors']['query']);
```

Here is the output:

```
array(1) {
  ["query"]=>
  string(71) "SELECT `request` FROM `track` WHERE (`time` >= '' AND `time` < '86400')"
}
Query was empty
```

Can someone tell me why does this happen?
I'm I using arrays in a wrong way?
How should I use them to this purpose?

Comment: Your query string is in: `$mysql["track"]["visitors"]["query"]` and not `$mysql["track"]["visitors"]`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is being stored in the ['query'] array according to var dump, but your mysql_query is using ["track"]. Try switching your query to ['query'] array.

Also please start using mysqli instead of mysql since the latter is deprecated. This is old code as you say, so I'm not sure if you were aware, but I thought I'd say it at least.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the code wrong while writing this answer. I've corrected the second code: mysql_query($mysql['track']['visitors']['query']);

Comment: About the mysql, I knew about it but I'm just testing a building the functions and I'm not familiar with the mysqli functions yet, so it's not important for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved! I missed to see that I was using the same array $mysql['track'] later on the code, wich was deleting the values in it!
Sorry for the ignorance, for sure I learned something with this.